# MongoDB - not able to connect

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I got a very strange situation and maybe someone of you can help me:

We are using a MongoDB Version 3.4 Community at Open Telekom Cloud. Its running for around a year or so without any problems. However when we try to connect to the database since 3 days now the connection cannot be established anymore. Also our services running in a cluster keep saying that they have problems to ping the database.

The Open Telekom Cloud uses a self signed certificate for connections from outside. This is how I try to connect to the DB through Mongo Shell:

```
mongo --host <IP> --port <Port> -u rwuser -p --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --sslCAFile ca.crt --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-01T13:08:16.791Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23321,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"ssl","preferredName":"tls"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-01T13:08:16.791Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23321,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"sslCAFile","preferredName":"tlsCAFile"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-01T13:08:16.791Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23321,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"sslAllowInvalidHostnames","preferredName":"tlsAllowInvalidHostnames"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-01T13:08:16.791Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23321,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"sslAllowInvalidCertificates","preferredName":"tlsAllowInvalidCertificates"}}
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://<IP>:<Port>/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server <IP>:<Port>, connection attempt failed: SocketException: stream truncated :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I searched for "stream truncated" in connection with mongo - but there is very few to nothing. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: You need to make sure the MongoDB Server (you are trying to connect to) is up and running.

Comment: What did the server log have to say about that connection attempt?

Comment: "Also our services running in a cluster keep saying that they have problems to ping the database." - This is very likely a networking issue, not a MongoDB issue. Make sure that the kubernetes cluster network is properly configured. Perhaps check "port forwarding"? Tell the ingest controller to point to the right service? Just throwing ideas out there